# How to serialize a QHash and a QMap in a single file?

Tags: serialization, qt5, qmap, qhash, qdatastream

I have a QHash and a seperate QMap. I can serialize them alone. But I would like to serilize them in a single file:

```
QMap<int,QString> myMap;
QHash<QString,MyCalss> myHash;
// .. fill: both have 4 (key,value) pairs.
// write here
QDataStream out (&myFile);
out<<myMap;
out<<myHash;
// read written
QDataStream in (&myFile);
in>>myMap>>myHash;
```

The last read (here myHash) is empty always. When I switch the ordering

```
QDataStream out (&myFile);
out<<myHash;
out<<myMap;
// read written
QDataStream in (&myFile);
in>>myHash>>myMap;
```

so here myMap is empty.

**How can I serialize both simultaneously?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with

```
QDataStream out (&myFile);
out<<myMap;
out<<myHash;
// read written
QDataStream in (&myFile);
in>>myMap;
in>>myHash;
```

Serializing 'in' into the Hash and the Hash into the Map will not lead to the desired results.